# Getting error with ". prepare_dataset.sh" command from lpot

Tags: python, tensorflow, intel-tensorflow, intel-lpot

I am following this github(https://github.com/intel/lpot/tree/master/examples/tensorflow/object_detection) for lpot and in the 5th step for downloading the dataset I am getting the below error.Unable to proceed.

```html
HEAD is now at 7a9934df Merged commit includes the following changes: 184048729  by Zhichao Lu:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py", line 46, in <module>
    flags = tf.app.flags
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
mv: cannot stat '/root/lpot/examples/tensorflow/object_detection/data/coco_testdev.record*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/root/lpot/examples/tensorflow/object_detection/data/coco_train.record*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/root/lpot/examples/tensorflow/object_detection/data/coco_val.record*': No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is tensorflow 2.0 or higher version then minor change in create_coco_tf_record.py code will resolve your issue.Replace **import tensorflow as tf** with **import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf**

Regards,

Janani Chandran